# Associating Multiple Date/Location Pairs to Node

Tags: views, datetime, location, entities

I'm attempting to create a custom content type in Drupal to represent concerts.  Each concert has a title, description, and multiple dates and locations (the concert may be performed on more than one day at different locations).

Since dates and locations are dependent on each other, I thought that the [Field Collection](http://drupal.org/project/field_collection) module would be ideal for me.  This module allowed me to group the date and location field and add multiple values; however, when I try to display the concerts in a calendar in Views (I've tried both Calendar and FullCalendar), I can't find a way to display the title of the concert because it is now in a separate entity.

Is there any way I could make my current content type work, or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Why is the title in a separate entity? Shouldn't you view be a node view of type concert, then the title is on the concert?

Comment: Since the Date field is in the Field Collection, when I create the calendar in Views, I only have access the the fields in the Field Collection.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to solve this by adding a relationship in the Views setup.  Now, I have access to all the fields of the host entity.